# Using ".printf(...)" in Java to print the value in memory

Tags: java, variables, memory, floating-point, printf

To begin: Yes, I know there exist similar questions regarding this, but primarily in other languages or doing other operations

I would like to print out the values, located in memory, of a variable. As in, the exact value, not the variable name.

For an integer value, I would like to print out the binary representation of whatever is located in binary. This can easily be done with conversions, but I'd like to use the value in memory for an example.

For a floating-point value, I again would like to print out exactly what is stored in memory, again as an example (for a research paper presentation).

For a non-primitive value, I would like to print out the address located in the variable's allocated space.

How would I do this? It doesn't necessarily have to use the "printf" method; I remember someone mentioning to me that it was possible to do it using "printf".

It was brought up that in Java you are unable to access the addresses in memory. Is it possible to access the values in memory themselves for primitive values? Or, would I be better off attempting to switch to another language?

Comment: "variable located in memory"? Where else would a variable be located?

Comment: @Andreas I put that to specify I wanted the actual value of the variable, located in memory instead not the name of the variable itself. I edited the post to better reflect this idea. My apologies.

Comment: Unlike C,you cannot access address(pointers) in Java

Comment: I'm fairly sure java chose not to expose references for security reason

Comment: If I can't access the addresses themselves, is it possible for me to access the raw binary values of the variables? For example, for an int iVal with the value 1, would it be possible for me to output "00000000000000000000000000000001" instead of "1"; and for the value "1.0", print out the binary representation of how the floating-point value "1.0" is represented in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does *not* give you direct access to anything stored in memory. The JVM is free to store any value in whatever form it wants, as long as it behaves as described in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). So your request is impossible.

You can get some "internal" values, but it may not be what's in memory.

> For an integer value, I would like to print out the binary representation of whatever is located in binary.

Use [`Long.toBinaryString(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString%28long%29) or [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29).

> For a floating-point value, I again would like to print out exactly what is stored in memory.

Use [`Double.doubleToRawLongBits(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) or [`Float.floatToRawIntBits(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29), then convert to binary as above.

For `boolean`, the value is either `true` or `false`. No internal representation is defined, e.g. a `boolean[10]` may be stored as 10 64-bit values of 0 or 1 (unlikely), as 10 bytes (likely), or as 2 bytes using the lower 10 bits. JVM's choice.

> For a non-primitive value, I would like to print out the address located in the variable's allocated space.

Not possible. These days, Java references are usually stored internally as a 32-bit [Compressed OOP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop), but you can't get it.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Would it be possible to access this in any other higher-level language (C, etc)?

Comment: Yes, `C` is a very lower-level language, providing direct memory access at the byte level. `C++` is just `C` with OO features. `C#` and other CLR languages are like Java's JVM.

Comment: @Andreas Alright, I suppose I'll attempt to learn C in three weeks then. I have to show in my research paper presentation an example of what my topic is covering; for my topic I chose floating-point inaccuracy and inconsistency.

Comment: Floating point numbers are usually stored as [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), any language that uses that can be used. The `doubleToRawLongBits()` method returns the IEEE 754 value. As the JLS says, "[The floating-point types are float and double, which are conceptually associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values and operations as specified in IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, ANSI/IEEE Standard 754-1985 (IEEE, New York)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)".

Comment: I didn't know that. I've actually been sitting here trying to attempt to get Institutional Access to that standard. I'll "play" around with some code and see what I can come up with. Thanks. @Andreas